# Yii2 Select2 widget issue showing unexpected output

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

Problem :

I was trying to build auto suggestion select box in my yii2 application.I have downloaded from here https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 and used select2 widget . below is my code

```
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use app\models\Contact;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
$data = ArrayHelper::map(Contact::find()->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->getId()])->orderBy('email')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'email');
echo $form->field($model, 'contact_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
'data' => $data,
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search a contact or add new','multiple' => true],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true,
    'tags' => true,
     'maximumInputLength' => 1000

],
```

]);

Here contact is model and give array data of email records like test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com
but when user search string in dropdownbox it produce output as attachment image
[image]

I tried

```
  $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

in my controller with respective action but no luck,
is there any other solution , i have google an hour but there no solution found

Comment: i am pretty sure that this is no code from the Select2 widget. This is some Javascript code which is added somewhere else in your form.

This JS code is also mentioned here: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2045816 it seems like some email protector.

Comment: can u post generated select option elements